# CorsWebFilter not working with secured routes that have hasAnyRole(...) assigned to them but works with those that are assigned with permitAll()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, spring-webflux

However all routes work when i am using postman. But in my javascript application only open routes work (those with permitAll()) and the secured routes return the error below even when i pass the right JWT token.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:8181/apiv1/shopping/find/user/5e2f5814ef8203356e078e16'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Here is my spring security configuration:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class AppSecurity(val authManager: AuthenticationManager,
                  val securityContextRepository: SecurityContextRepository) {

    @Bean
    fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        return http.csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .authenticationManager(authManager)
                .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/apiv1/user", "/apiv1/user/login").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/apiv1/user", "/apiv1/user/**").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/apiv1/shopping/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_ADMIN")
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/apiv1/shopping/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_ADMIN")
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and().build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun corsWebFilter(): CorsWebFilter {
        val corsConfig = CorsConfiguration()
        corsConfig.allowCredentials = true
        corsConfig.allowedOrigins = mutableListOf("*")
        corsConfig.allowedMethods = mutableListOf("*")
        corsConfig.allowedHeaders = mutableListOf("*")

        val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig)

        return CorsWebFilter(source)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it by following the official documentation in the link below. The main point was CORS must be processed before spring security.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#cors

Here is my final code:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
class AppSecurity(val authManager: AuthenticationManager,
                  val securityContextRepository: SecurityContextRepository) {

    @Bean
    fun securityWebFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        return http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults()).csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .authenticationManager(authManager)
                .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/apiv1/user", "/apiv1/user/login").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/apiv1/user", "/apiv1/user/**").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/apiv1/shopping/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_ADMIN")
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/apiv1/shopping/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_ADMIN")
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and().build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun corsConfigurationSource(): CorsConfigurationSource {
        val configuration = CorsConfiguration()
        configuration.allowCredentials = true
        configuration.allowedOrigins = mutableListOf("*")
        configuration.allowedMethods = mutableListOf("*")
        configuration.allowedHeaders = mutableListOf("*")
        val source = UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource()
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration)
        return source
    }
}
```